# Project in Nx monorepo to hold a library's type definition

Tags: typescript-typings, nrwl-nx

I would like to add a lib in my Nx monorepo which adds type definition (for Typescript) to an existing pure-javascript library (which lives outside the monorepo).

Did anyone already try something like this? Is it possible without a separate project (have the typings outside the monorepo)? Can you point me some examples/litterature?

I naively thought it would have been enough to name the lib `@types/scope__the-lib` to make everything works (like `npm install @types/scope__the-lib` adds a folder in `node_modules/@types` used by typescript as a location of typings files), but I'm missing some parts.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out a solution to this? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don’t have a solution right now … at least I’m not alone now, which make me feel a little bit less crazy . It’s a start !